Я создал игру на pygame но не могу переделать ее под андроид то есть надо чтоб работал сенсор, как это сделать?
Я создал игру на pygame но не могу переделать ее под андроид то есть надо чтоб работал сенсор, как это сделать?

Пожалуйста, изучайте и пользуйтесь, всё уже описано: https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example
